# Which set of graphics drivers to download?

Tags: 17.10, radeon, amd-graphics

I've recently dual booted the Ubuntu 17.10.1 with wubi alongside Windows 10 on my Asus X53U laptop which came with the AMD Radeon HD 6290 graphics card.
As all of us know that the fglrx is no longer supported from the Ubuntu 16.0 versions so there was an alternative The Amdgpu-Pro and the Radeon-Pro Open source drivers. But the problem is that due to my device being old I can't find the right one to install to my laptop. I got a link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Testing_the_driver) which lists the Radeon HD 6000M gpu series I've got, but there are no download links. Also the Amdgpu is only supported for newer AMD GPUs. What can i do now, can anyone provide me a full exhaustive list of all supported hardwares (not the one in the AMD official site) and download links for the driver my hardware supports. I'm facing tremendous performance issues.

Also:
When I enter the lspci command at the terminal to check the graphics drivers it says this  ... VGA... Advanced Micro Devices (graphics card name here)

```
Subsystem: AsusTek...
kernel modules: radeon
```

Now what does the kernel modules mean, I think if the correct driver is running it should have been something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radeon driver should work for you. (the one that is already used as indicated by the `lspci` output)

You will also need the packages `xserver-xorg-video-ati` and `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`. X should do the rest automatically. But if you want to force it you have to set the driver to `radeon`.

a full list of supported cards and features is available [here](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/) (See the decoder ring at the bottom. I think you have an Evergreen Card. this is why you need radeon and not amdgpu)

Comment: First of all my card is not evergreen (as only the 6350 was evergreen in the 6000M series), moreover the page you directed to was very old. Much changed after Ubuntu updated from 15 to 16 and removing support for proprietary drivers from AMD. Does that mean I will have no driver to install at all 

Comment: Radeon HD 6290 is has the [Terrascale 2 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_6000_Series#Northern_Islands_(HD_6xxx)_Series), which makes it Evergreen. 
The page is also not very old. Last edit is 2 month old. imho this page is the most reliable source for information about the radeon driver

Comment: I've already started to install the oibaf drivers, let's see what happens.

Comment: oibaf is not a driver it is a ppa that offers bleeding edge drivers. This will in the end result in the fact that you will have slightly newer version of `xserver-xorg-video-ati`, which is the driver I linked you to in my original post.

Comment: I finished the installation but the problem still persists. I'm unable to get good performance not even near to the one i get on my Win 10 with the correct drivers installed. My present situation seems exactly similar to not having the AMD drivers on Win 10 and letting the Microsoft video driver to do the job, which is a terrible experience

Comment: and BTW how to install this driver http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man4/radeon.4.html

Comment: You  probably already have it installed and are using it.  Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (look e.g. for `connected`).  If not see my original answer. It has all the information you need. The performance of the free drivers is not as good as that of the proprietary ones. See e.g. this comparison by (phornoix)[https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-45-amdgpurad&num=1].

Comment: One more thing is that while installing Ubuntu for the second time, I noticed a change. During the second installation I chose the option to install in safe graphics mode, so when the installation went this time it was much smoother and there was no screen flickering as it was there during the first time. Also while in the installer screen where 'what's new' or 'what's exciting' something like that is shown, the graphics card seemed to work seamlessly as it should, but after the installation when I boot into the system I get the same graphics driver problem.

Comment: So can you tell me HOW TO REMAIN PERMANENTLY IN SAFE GRAPHICS MODE?

Comment: Save mode probably uses the `vesa` driver, which is sort of minimal compromise. I would not recommend to use that. 
If I get you right you are experiencing some sort of graphics problems? Perhaps this is worth another question.

Comment: I'll try adding another question perhaps.